# "I wanted to say" is it because the lecturer made this video in the past and the audience necessarily watch the video later?

Tags: tense

It sounds like that the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/m_0lDnW-WD0?t=267)

> i wanted to say

is it because the lecturer made this video in the past and the audience necessarily watch the video later?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's a common phrase in this context, and suggests diffidence or tentativeness. The implication is something like "I wanted to say this, if that's all right with you" - it is the conditional use of the past rather than a true past.

It doesn't necessarily signal that the speaker is genuinely feeling diffident or tentative, but it somehow makes it seem more polite.